# keras merge concatenate failed because of different input shape even though input shape are the same

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to concatenate 4 different layers into one layer to input into the next part of my model. I am using the Keras functional API and the code is shown below.

```
# Concat left side 4 inputs and right side 4 inputs
print(lc,l1_conv_net,l2_conv_net,l3_conv_net)
left_combined = merge.Concatenate()([lc, l1_conv_net, l2_conv_net, l3_conv_net])
```

This errors occurs which says that my input shape is not the same. However, I also printed the input shape and it is seems to be the same except along the concat axis (which is the shape[1] since shape[0]=? is the number of examples in the batch).

```
Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 6), dtype=float32) Tensor("add_3/add_1:0", shape=(?, 100), dtype=float32) Tensor("add_6/add_1:0", shape=(?, 100), dtype=float32) Tensor("add_9/add_1:0", shape=(?, 100), dtype=float32)

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 6), (None, 7, 62), (None, 23, 62), (None, 2, 62)]
```

Coincidentally, the shape (None, 7, 62), (None, 23, 62), (None, 2, 62) is the input tensor shape for another custom keras layer which produces l1_conv_net as shown below:

```
l1_conv_net = build_graph_conv_net_fp_only([l1x, l1y, l1z],
                                                   conv_layer_sizes=self.conv_width,
                                                   fp_layer_size=self.fp_length,
                                                   conv_activation='relu', fp_activation='softmax')
```

So the print statement says that the shape is (?,6), (?,100) , (?,100) , (?,100) but the keras merge function reads it as [(None, 6), (None, 7, 62), (None, 23, 62), (None, 2, 62)] ? Why is this so?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it is the same `Concatenate` layer? Seems like another concat layer with different inputs is causing the error not the one you put the code for.

Comment: It is the same concat layer as I followed the line error to that line :( It is so strange though as the line right before that merge layer shows that the shape is all the same...

Comment: Even the print is showing different shapes... Use `print(K.int_shape(tensor))` to print proper shapes. Don't print tensors, the conversation between keras and tensorflow might be a little twisted.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found that the error was because the custom layer was using Keras1 where it is get_output_shape whereas Keras2 must be converted to compute_output_shape. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

So.... if the message says you're using these shapes, then you can't concatenate....

```
[(None, 6), (None, 7, 62), (None, 23, 62), (None, 2, 62)]
```

You can try to concatenate the last three:

```
left_combined = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([l1_conv_net, l2_conv_net, l3_conv_net])
```

Don't print tensors, print `K.int_shape(tensor)` to see the actual shapes. (By the way, something is really going wrong with what you posted because the shapes of the tensors are too weird. The Keras shapes make sense if you're using 1D convolutions or RNNs)

If your backend is not tensorflow, you may have wrong `output_shape` parameters in custom or lambda layers somewhere.

Comment: You are right. The custome layer output_shape method was wrong. I changed the method in the class layer from get_output_shape to compute_output_shape and everything wrongs as expected!

Comment: Great :)) - If you consider that this answers your question, please mark it as answered. @LimKaizhuo

Answer (score 0):

Keras concatenate has some restrictions. The number of dimensions has to be the same, that's why your first tensor fails. You can save that quite quickly by reshaping it to (None, 1, 62). If you are merging along the first axis, all None dimensions have to be the same in the calculations. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py#L320), it appears that having an axis as None is not a problem in itself.

So reshape the first tensor and check whether the None axis will always be the same for all axes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big expert, yet for my case  defining the input like that  Input(shape=(1,1,) instead of this  Input(shape=(1,)) , added the required dimension and merge was excepted... just try to add a dimension with length 1.

Answer (score 0):

one good solution for concatenating output or intermediate layers is to Flatten them before concatenation:

```
l1_conv_net_features=Flatten(name="flatten_l1_conv_net")(l1_conv_net)
l2_conv_net_features=Flatten(name="flatten_l2_conv_net")(l2_conv_net)
l3_conv_net_features=Flatten(name="flatten_l3_conv_net")(l3_conv_net)
all_features = concatenate([l1_conv_net_features, l2_conv_net_features,l3_conv_net_features])
```