# Keras Model StagingError: in converted code

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a keras model which is a simple recommender system on the `movielens` dataset. I am converting `movie_id` and `user_id` to embedding (through the training process, not pretrained embedding) and also passing a few other features (zip_code, age, sex) as training input.

```
x_train.shape
(90000, 5)

EMBEDDING_SIZE = 50
NUM_USERS =movielens['user_id'].nunique()
NUM_MOVIES = movielens['movie_id'].nunique()
```

Model code below:

```
class RecommenderDNN(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_users, num_movies, embedding_size, **kwargs):
        super(RecommenderDNN, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_users = num_users
        self.num_movies = num_movies
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.user_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            num_users,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
        )

        self.movie_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            num_movies,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
        )


    def call(self, inputs):
        user_vector = self.user_embedding(inputs[:, 0])


        movie_vector = self.movie_embedding(inputs[:, 1])

        zip_code = inputs[:, 2]
        age = inputs[:, 3]
        gender = inputs[:,4]

        concat = layers.concatenate([user_vector, movie_vector, zip_code, age, gender], axis=1)
        concat_dropout = layers.Dropout(0.2)(concat)
        dense_1 = layers.Dense(100,name='FullyConnected', activation='relu')(concat)
        dropout_1 = layers.Dropout(0.2,name='Dropout')(dense_1)
        dense_2 = layers.Dense(50,name='FullyConnected-1', activation='relu')(dense_1)
        dropout_2 = layers.Dropout(0.2,name='Dropout')(dense_2)
        dense_3 = layers.Dense(20,name='FullyConnected-2', activation='relu')(dense_2)
        dropout_3 = layers.Dropout(0.2,name='Dropout')(dense_3)
        dense_4 = layers.Dense(10,name='FullyConnected-3', activation='relu')(dense_3)


        result = layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax',name='Activation')(dense_4)


model = RecommenderDNN(NUM_USERS, NUM_MOVIES, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
)

callbk = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping('val_loss', patience=5), 
keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('recdnn.h5', save_best_only=True)]
```

When I run the training

```
history = model.fit(
    x=x_train,
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=100,
    epochs=10,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
    callbacks = callbk
)
```

I get below error

```
StagingError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-89-c1ff8dd57123>:33 call  *
        concat = layers.concatenate([user_vector, movie_vector, zip_code, age, gender], axis=1)
    /Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/merge.py:716 concatenate
        return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)
    /Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:748 __call__
        self._maybe_build(inputs)
    /Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:2116 _maybe_build
        self.build(input_shapes)
    /Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py:306 wrapper
        output_shape = fn(instance, input_shape)
    /Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/merge.py:382 build
        del reduced_inputs_shapes[i][self.axis]

    IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Seems something is off in `concat = layers.concatenate([user_vector, movie_vector, zip_code, age, gender], axis=1)` but not sure what it is.

**EDIT**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611946/keras-merge-concatenate-failed-because-of-different-input-shape-even-though-inpu), it looks like for `layers.concatenate` to work, all the input needs to be of the same shape. But I am still not sure how to do that in my specific case.

Please suggest.

Comment: Embedding layer returns 3D tensor with shape `(batch_size, input_length, output_dim)`, so it can't be concatenated with 2D tensors `zip_code`, `age`, `gender`.

Comment: @maciek97x any suggestion what to do then?

Comment: @maciek97x also I printed out `user_vector.shape`, `movie_vector.shape`, `zip_code.shape`, `age.shape`, `gender.shape` and they are `(None, 50)`, `(None, 50)`, `(None,)`, `(None,)`, `(None,)`. So I do not see how the embedding layer is returning 3D tensor.

Comment: Then you should change shapes `(None,)` to `(None,1)`, because they are 1D tensors. It could be done with `tf.keras.backend.expand_dims`.

Comment: I did the conversion with `zip_code = zip_code[: ,None]` but get into error  `TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, float32, string, string, string] that don't all match.`. Then I update the reshape code to `zip_code = float(zip_code[:,None])` but now getting error `ValueError: A layer's call method should return a Tensor or a list of Tensors, not None (layer: recommender_dnn_13).` I guess it is a whole differernt problem now.

Comment: What are the values of `zip_code`, `age` and `sex`? If they are strings, then you should somehow parse them to float. For example in `sex` change male to 0 and female to 1.

Comment: @maciek97x I wonder why the error refers to `zip_code`, `age`, `sex` to string? I did LabelEncoding for them so they are all `int` when I check after feature conversion. But somehow inside the model definition it is treating them as string? Inside the model definition I changed it to float `zip_code = float(inputs[:, 2])` for example. You are correct about `sex` change. That was done through Label Encoding in the feature engineering phase.

Comment: Could you attach code that prepares `x_train` to the question?

Comment: @maciek97x please see the post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244655/keras-typeerror-expected-float32-got-tf-tensor-of-type-tensor-instead

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this particular issue by reshaping like below

```
zip_code = zip_code[: ,None]
age = age[: ,None]
gender = gender[: ,None]
```

I have a different issue now but that is a [different discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244655/keras-typeerror-expected-float32-got-tf-tensor-of-type-tensor-instead).