# Keras TypeError: Expected float32, got <tf.Tensor ..>of type 'Tensor' instead

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning

I have a Keras model which gives me error

```
TypeError: Expected float32, got <tf.Tensor 'recommender_dnn_25/strided_slice_5:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32> of type 'Tensor' instead.
```

To my keras model, I am sending train/validation data of type `numpy.ndarray`. This is from `movielens` dataset and the values are `movie_id`, `user_id`, `zip_code`, `age`, `gender`. A sample row below:

```
x_train[0]
array(['195', '241', 415, 3, 1], dtype=object)
```

The 1st two inputs are trained to an embedding along with the model training process. The last three (zip_code, age, gender) goes through below conversion before all five of the features are concatenated.

1. converted to float
2. reshaped to (None,1)
3. converted to tensor using `zip_code = K.constant(zip_code)`, Without this step I see error `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)`

Now when I run this model - I get error `TypeError: Expected float32, got <tf.Tensor 'recommender_dnn_25/strided_slice_5:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32> of type 'Tensor' instead.`

The error is happening at `zip_code = K.constant(zip_code)` even before it gets into the concatenate phase.

Below model code:

```
x_train.shape
(90000, 5)

EMBEDDING_SIZE = 50
NUM_USERS =movielens['user_id'].nunique()
NUM_MOVIES = movielens['movie_id'].nunique()

class RecommenderDNN(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_users, num_movies, embedding_size, **kwargs):
        super(RecommenderDNN, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_users = num_users
        self.num_movies = num_movies
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.user_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            num_users,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
        )
        self.movie_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            num_movies,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
        )


    def call(self, inputs):
        user_vector = self.user_embedding(inputs[:, 0])

        movie_vector = self.movie_embedding(inputs[:, 1])

        zip_code = float(inputs[:, 2])
        age = float(inputs[:, 3])
        gender = float(inputs[:,4])

        zip_code = zip_code[: ,None]
        age = age[: ,None]
        gender = gender[: ,None]

        zip_code = K.constant(zip_code)
        age = K.constant(age)
        gender = K.constant(gender)


        print(user_vector.shape)
        print(movie_vector.shape)
        print(zip_code.shape)
        print(age.shape)
        print(gender.shape)


        concat = layers.concatenate([user_vector, movie_vector, zip_code, age, gender], axis=1)
        concat_dropout = layers.Dropout(0.2)(concat)
        # rest of the layers ...
        result = layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax',name='Activation')(dense_4)
        return result


model = RecommenderDNN(NUM_USERS, NUM_MOVIES, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Try using `tf.convert_to_tensor` instead of `K.constant`.

Comment: @maciek97x it gives me back the error I got without using `K.constant`  which is mentioned at step 3 `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).`

Comment: Hmm, then try converting `zip_code` to tensor of floats with `.astype(np.float64)`.

Comment: @maciek97x what is the sequence of conversion operation then? suppose I read `zip_code` like this `zip_code = inputs[:, 2]` Whats next?

Comment: I think `zip_code = inputs[:, 2].astype(np.float64)` and then `zip_code = zip_code [:, None]` should work.

Comment: @maciek97x it gives me error `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Comment: Its strange that before there was error telling it's a NumPy array and now another error tells it's a Tensor. Anyway, try using `tf.cast` instead of `astype` to change its dtype.

Comment: I am struggling with the same strange issue. Any solutions in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine like this:

```
kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.min_max_norm
```

=>

```
kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.MinMaxNorm()
```

probably just need to add parentheses (Y)

Answer (score -1):

What I was doing had some fundamental problems. I was concatenating the embedding layers with the categorical input. The embedding layer outputs a 3D tensor (although printing out `.shape` only shows 2D, not sure why). Combining it with the input categorical without passing the categorical though any other layer does not really make sense. So I `flattened` the embedding layer output and passed the input categorical through a `Dense` layer before concatenating them.

For simplicity, lets assume we have 2 features - `user_id` and `age`. We want to generate embedding for the `user_id` through the training process. And `age` is the categorical variable that is passed as the model input after `LabelEncoding`.

Below code that resolved the issue:

```
row_count = train.shape[0]
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 50
NUM_USERS = movielens['user_id'].nunique()

user_input = keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='user')
age_input = keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='age')
user_emb = layers.Embedding(output_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE, input_dim=NUM_USERS+1, input_length=row_count, name='user_emb')(user_input)
user_vec = layers.Flatten(name='FlattenUser')(user_emb)
dense_1 = layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(age_input)
concat = layers.concatenate([user_vec, dense_1], axis=1)
dense = layers.Dense(10,name='FullyConnected')(concat)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax") (dense)
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.005)
model = keras.Model([user_input, age_input], outputs)
model.compile(optimizer=adam,loss= 'mean_absolute_error')
```